# Rails Query Not getting Executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a scenario in my app which happens sometimes in Production, that the query doesn't get executed or even if it did, it didn't do what it was suppose to do. For example I was going through my production logs. for example

```
D, [2020-06-09T02:31:41.389369 #9969] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT "promo_codes"."code" FROM "promo_codes" WHERE "promo_codes"."id" IN (527, 530)

D, [2020-06-09T02:31:41.392417 #9969] DEBUG -- :[1m[36mSQL (2.7ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "promo_code" WHERE "promo_code"."user_id" = $1[0m  [["user_id", 12]]


D, [2020-06-09T02:31:41.393176 #9969] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  BEGIN


D, [2020-06-09T02:31:41.394689 #9969] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mCity Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 115570]]


D, [2020-06-09T02:31:41.397179 #9969] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "addon_2_total_price" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5 , ["addon_2_total_price", "11.0"], ["updated_at", "2020-06-09 02:31:41.395437"], ["id", 12]]
```

But I looked into db the records and there and they didn't got deleted and logs also didn't show any error.

This is the code

```
current_user.promo_code_uses.delete_all
```

So this runs fine like most of the time. (maybe 99% of the time)
Can there be any scenario that query didn't get executed or missed?

Comment: Please be specific and post the Rails code generating the query and the log lines around the one you posted. Do other queries work fine? Try running the query yourself on the rails console (`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails console`) and see what happens (be careful messing with production databases).

Comment: Did you check if there's any constraint preventing it to be destroyed?

Comment: @FelipeZavan i have updated the question. and yes the other queries in this method above and below this line of code worked fine

Comment: Good afternoon.
Please check:
1) is the transaction open
2) is there a transaction nested
3) whether an open transaction is canceled by an exception